# Can't get data through CodeIgniter query builder from and ODBC Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

i'm trying to create a login page with Codeigniter where i need to collect data from an MS SQL Database using an ODBC connection but i get the following error:

> Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::select().

Why does it happen and how can i fix this? It's the first time im using CI query builder to connect to an ODBC MS SQL database

**Model**

```
class Utilizador_model extends CI_Model {



    public function login($username,$password){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('utilizadores');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $q = $this->db->get();

            if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
             return $q->result_array();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I have tried something like this :

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from utilizadores where username = "'.$username.'" AND password ='.$password);
    $resultado = $query->result_array();

    return $resultado;
```

But i get the following error:

> Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'F'., SQL state S0022 in
>   SQLExecDirect

'F' was what i typed on the input

Comment: I've done that before i call the function, i just need to know how to get the info from the db

Comment: that's not even the point of this post tbh

Comment: Hey @mario, I know this is not what you are asking, but you look like you are asking for sql injection attacks with that (second example) code there.  (You may be doing a sql injection attack on yourself that isn't actually working)

Regarding your question, examine how you are quoting your sql.  I believe the values are not quoted properly so sql server thinks you are trying to compare two fields rather than a field against a string.

Again, though, please rethink how you are doing this and use proper sql interpolation rather than concatenating strings containing user input.

Comment: The model code looks better in this respect. (from my comment above)

Comment: im using addslashes() in each variable on the controller before its sends the values to the model. is this enough to prevent sql injections right?

Answer (score 1):

This might work instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // return array
} else {
  return false;
}
```

This is similar to what I use with the mysqli library, but I don't know if it is something you are willing to incorporate into your project. It is a breeze to work with.

Also, it seems your method may be storing the passwords in cleartext, which is not a good idea.

**EDIT**- This is how I create my connection:

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**EDIT #2**: The issue was using double quotes instead of single quotes. Please, nobody else fall into this demonic trap.

Comment: yeah i mean, forget the password stuff, i got that handled i just want to know how to get the data with CI

Comment: @MarcoSilva it is suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219874) that you could fix this issue by swapping your single and double quotes as I have

Comment: @MarcoSilva SQL is very specific out of what it wants in formatting. My advice is to just accept it and get on with life because it'll have you tearing your hair out. If this helped, please mark as accepted answer :)